# Android 11 file system and cloud storage

Tags: sync, android-11, cloud

I have documents stored in the cloud, and I used to have a use case like this:

1. I edit documents on a PC
2. These documents are automatically uploaded to the cloud
3. I download documents to my phone via the application

But after buying a smartphone on Android 11, I ran into a problem that it was no longer possible to download files to the folder I needed because of updates in the file system, but the application still allows you to download to the Downloads folder, but the whole trouble is that the application stopped seeing files with the same name and offering to "Replace" them"or "Skip", but simply duplicates each time adding an index at the end of the name, which negates the use of the cloud, because you constantly have to keep in mind that after uploading documents you need to go in and delete all the old files (and there may be a lot of documents).

Is there any solution so that when downloading files, it is possible to replace files, and not duplicate them

Comment: If using a third party app is OK for you, use [folder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) app. Firstly, you can set up to download into your desired folder instead of default "downloads" folder. Second, it has a rich set of options that give you good flexibility in syncing to/from cloud//I use it extensively and even use an automation app to sync without user interaction// consider [edit]ing your question to make it clear-for instance I don't know what "application" you are talking about "*trouble is that the application stopped*"

Comment: Thirdly, You won't need to alter your work flow by deleting cloud backups just to get right files synced to your device.